# FileZilla is saying there is an error in the W3.org link!

Tags: html, xampp, w3c

I just got my free web hosting set up (trigoblocks.comuf.com), I connected via FileZilla FTP and uploaded my files. The error I get is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a3639879/public_html/header.php on line 1". 
Header.php line 1-2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

I do not get this error while on localhost with XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the `<?` in `<?xml` is a PHP short tag.

Change the first line to:

```
<?php print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"; ?>
```

to fix this, or disable PHP's short tags.